# Question about Using Selenium with Python to Log in to Gmail

Tags: python, selenium, gmail, bots

I am trying to log in to my gmail account via Selenium on Python and the problem is: **I can enter the username correctly, but nothing is entered into the password section**

To put in context, for Gmail, you have to put your username in, then move on to the password section after. I have attempted to do the following solutions:
- refreshing the page in between entering username and pword (this causes you to go to some other screen)
- waiting for the password box to appear (didn't make any change)
- trying to access the box by id instead of xpath (didn't work)

Here is my code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
#from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

keys = {
    'url':'http://www.gmail.com',
    'username':'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'pword':'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'email':'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'title':'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'text':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}

driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get(keys['url'])
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys(keys['username'])
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/content/span').click()

# wait for the password field to be visible
#wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
#passwordElem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "Passwd")))
#passwordElem.clear()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys(keys['pword'])
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/content').click()
```

The commented sections are the edits I attempted to make.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use IMAP to access your email account ?

Comment: automating gmail or any googles app is against there terms of service

Comment: @MauriceMeyer- Thanks, I will have a look into it.

Comment: @Dev- I wasn't aware of that, thanks for letting me know. I have just started learning about using selenium and I thought it the email thing would be an interesting use. Perhaps I will try creating a new project.

Answer (score 0):

add `sleep` after clicking next button

```
....
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/content/span').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys(keys['pword'])
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/content').click()
```

or using `WebDriverWait`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/content/span').click()

# wait for the password field to be visible
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) # not "browser"
passwordElem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password"))) # not By.ID
passwordElem.send_keys(keys['pword'])
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/content').click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have made the edits that you have posted, but it still just does nothing at the password screen. I wonder if perhaps they have made the website such that it cannot be accessed by program (at least in this fashion)

Comment: I made change for using `WebDriverWait` try it.